# Counting the unique values in a column from another list, based on criteria Excel

Tags: excel

I think I've tried every example I've managed to find on google but can't seem to get what I'm looking for here.

```
List 1: A, B
List 2: A, B, D, E, F, G
```

List 2 is part of a pivot table, with a named range TEST.

My Problem:

I'm trying to count the unique values from List 2, which appear in List 1 and TEST = "".

I've tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(TEST,"",List 2, List 1))
```

however this does not give a unique count, it includes duplicates.

I've also tried:

```
{=COUNTIFS(TEST,"",List 2, List 1))}
```

however this gives me a value of 1 (I'm expecting 2, can't explain why it's not giving 2)

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the list1 is unique this will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIFS(TEST,"",List 2, List 1)>0))
```

Comment: Care to explain please mate? I'm sure it works but would love to understand the method

Comment: Instead of adding the result of the COUNTIF it will count `1` for anytime the countif returns a value greater than `0`

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear, I get the formula, its the 2 `-` that are throwing me

Comment: It is a double Uinary.  What it does is multiply the Boolean by `-1*-1` which turns it into 1s and 0s.

Comment: @Zac try having a look [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) (:

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: Thanks @p._phidot_